# Using local in a forvalues loop reports a syntax error

Tags: stata

I am using two-level loops to create a set of variables. But Stata reports a syntax error.

```
    forvalues i = 1/5 {
        local to `i'+1
        dis `to'

        forvalues j = `to'/6{
            dis `j'
            gen e_`i'_`j' = .
        }

    }
```

I could not figure out where I made the syntax error.

And a follow-up question. I would like to change how the number of loops are coded in the example above. Right now, it's hard-coded as 5 and 6. But I want to make it based on the data. For instance,I am coding as below:

```
        sum x
        scalar x_max_1 = `r(max)'-1
        scalar x_max_2 = `r(max)'

        forvalues i = 1/x_max_1 {
        local to = `i'+1
        dis `to'

        forvalues j = `to'/x_max_2{
            dis `j'
            gen e_`i'_`j' = .
        }

    }
```

However, Stata reports a syntax error in this case. I am not sure why. The scalar is a numeric variable. Why would the code above not work?

Comment: Scalars are **not** variables so far as Stata is concerned. Sure, in several other languages the equivalent would be called variables. But on Stata questions only Stata terminology is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be better as

```
forvalues i = 1/5 {
    local to = `i' + 1
    forvalues j = `to'/6 {
        gen e_`i'_`j' = .
    }
}
```

With your code you went

```
local to `i' + 1
```

so first time around the loop `to` becomes the string or text `1 + 1` which is then illegal as an argument to `forvalues`. That is, a `local` definition without an `=` sign will result in copying of text, not evaluation of the expression.

The way you used `display` could not show you this error because `display` used that way will evaluate expressions to the extent possible. If you had insisted that the macro was a string with

```
di "`to'"
```

then you would have seen its contents.

Another way to do it is

```
forvalues i = 1/5 {
    forvalues j = `= `i' + 1'/6 {
        gen e_`i'_`j' = .
    }
}
```

EDIT

You asked further about

```
sum x
scalar x_max_1 = `r(max)'-1
scalar x_max_2 = `r(max)'

forvalues i = 1/x_max_1 {
```

and quite a lot can be said about that. Let's work backwards from one of various better solutions:

```
sum x, meanonly 
forvalues i = 1/`= r(max) - 1' {
```

or another, perhaps a little more transparent:

```
sum x, meanonly 
local max = r(max) - 1 

forvalues i = 1/`max' {
```

What are the messages here:

1. If you only want the maximum, specify `meanonly`. Agreed: the option name alone does not imply this. See https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0135 for more.
2. What is the point of pushing the r-class result `r(max)` into a `scalar`? You already have what you need in `r(max)`. Educate yourself out of this with the following analogy.

*I have what I want. Now I put it into a box. Now I take it out of the box. Now I have what I want again. Come to think of it, the box business can be cut.*

The box is the `scalar`, two `scalar`s in this case.

3. `forvalues` won't evaluate scalars to give you the number you want. That will happen in many languages, but not here.
4. More subtly, `forvalues` doesn't even evaluate `local` references or similar constructs. What happens is that Stata's generic syntax parser does that for you before what you typed is passed to `forvalues`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the long answer. I understand that I can use local macros instead of scalar in the frovalues statement. I simply could not figure out if it's not allowed in Stata or I did something wrong mysteriously in the scalar construction step.

Comment: Both errors have the same flavour. `forvalues` will not itself evaluate scalars or expressions on the fly. So, you can choose: do the evaluation before you enter the loop or use local macros or equivalent expressions.